# Rebus send from Bus2 in Bus1's messagehandler

Tags: c#, messaging, rebus

I have to Rebus buses that use Azure ServiceBus, but when I try to send to from Bus2 in one of Bus1's messagehandlers this does not work. The message is not sent.

Any thoughts ?

EDIT

Bus 1

```
        string padesQueueAddress = "padesworker";
        int numberOfWorkes = Settings.NumberOfWorkers>0   Settings.NumberOfWorkers:10;

        string errorQueueAddress = string.Format("{0}-error", queueAddress);

        var adapter = new AutofacContainerAdapter(Container);
        Bus = Configure.With(adapter)
             .Logging(l =>  l.Use(UseRaygunRebusLoggingFactory(rayclient,Settings.Debug ? RaygunLoggerLevel.DEBUG :  RaygunLoggerLevel.WARN)))
             .Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus( Settings.AzureQueueConnectionString, queueAddress,AzureServiceBusMode.Standard))                                  
             .Sagas(s => s.StoreInSqlServer(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Settings.RebusSagaSqlConnectionString) ? Settings.AzureSqlConnectionString : Settings.RebusSagaSqlConnectionString, "Saga", "SagaIndex") )
             .Routing(r => r.TypeBased().MapAssemblyOf<SendSmsCommand>(queueAddress).MapAssemblyOf<Unipluss.Sign.Pades.Commands.CreatePadesCommand>(padesQueueAddress))                 
            .Options(o =>
            {
                o.SimpleRetryStrategy(secondLevelRetriesEnabled: true, maxDeliveryAttempts:5,errorQueueAddress: errorQueueAddress);

                o.SetNumberOfWorkers(numberOfWorkes);
                o.SetMaxParallelism(numberOfWorkes);                    

            })                
            .Start();

        await Bus.SendLocal(new HeartBeatCommand());
```

Bus 2

```
    private  IBus CreateExternalEventBus()
    {

        var eventBus = Configure.With(new BuiltinHandlerActivator())
                .Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus(Settings.EventServiceBusConnectionString, queueAddress+"_event", AzureServiceBusMode.Basic))
                .Logging(x=>x.ColoredConsole(LogLevel.Debug))
                .Options(o =>
                {

                o.LogPipeline(true);
                o.EnableCompression();
                o.EnableEncryption(Settings.RebusEncryptionExternalEvents);
                })
                .Start();

        eventBus.Advanced.Routing.Send("1dd0f6f9422146048516a30f00aef4e5",new Unipluss.Sign.Events.Entities.DocumentCancledEvent() {CancledMessage = "test",DocumentId = Guid.NewGuid()});

        return eventBus;

    }
```

The eventBus send with the hardcoded send is working, but when this i sent from within one of Bus1's message handler the message is not sent (With logging on the logger says that the message is sent but it does appear in the queue).

Bus 2 is wrapped in a wrapper class an then injected in to Autofac to avoid having to IBus interfaces in Autofac.

```
        builder.Register(c => new ExternalEventsBus(CreateExternalEventBus()))
 .As<IExternalEventsBus>().SingleInstance();

public class ExternalEventsBus:IExternalEventsBus
{
    private IBus Bus;

    public ExternalEventsBus(IBus bus)
    {
        Bus = bus;
    }

    public async Task Send(object message, Guid documentProviderId)
    {
        await Bus.Advanced.Routing.Send(documentProviderId.ToString("n"), message);

    }

    public Task Send(object message, DocumentProvider documentProvider)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(documentProvider.RebusQueueConnectionString))
            return Send(message, documentProvider.Id);

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(Bus!=null)
            Bus.Dispose();
    }
}
```

IExternalEventsBus is then used in multiple messagehandlers in Bus1.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about the two buses' input queue names, routing setup, etc.?

Comment: I would love to help you :) please let me know some more about what you're trying to do, and how you're trying to do it....

Comment: I'm having a "internal queue" (using Azure ServiceBus and Rebus) referred as Bus1. Then we have a second external queue (also using Azure ServiceBus and Rebus)  referred to as Bus2. When events occur, Bus1 saves states and data to DB, and then sends a message to Bus2. Each account can enable events on their account and are given their own queue. The problem occurs when sending a message to Bus2 inside from a MessageHandler belonging to Bus1. When I do Bus2.Send from my service this works just fine, but when I do Bus2.Send inside a Handle(Message message) function the message does not get sent.

Comment: For Bus 1 (internal) are using "normal" routing where all messages live in one assembly. For Bus2 (external) we do not use routing because we send the message to a named queue (the customer accounts id witch is a guid), using Bus.Advanced.Routing.Send("guid",message).

Comment: it would help a lot if you could edit the original question and paste the relevant bits of code, i.e. the configuration bits and the bits where messages get sent

Comment: I could paste inn the configuration, but the message is sent via services that get the Bus injected via Autofac so it no that simple.

Comment: I'm just looking for the `Configure.With(...)` bits and the `await _bus.Send(..)` bits ...

Answer (score 1):

Ok... let me see if I understand this (please correct me if I am wrong):

You have two bus instances in your process:

1. One that uses an input queue with the value specified by `queueAddress`, which you did not include here.
2. Another one (the "external event bus") that has an input queue with the value specified by `queueAddress+"_event"`, which you also did not include here.

It seems like the purpose of your bus instances is that the first one is used to coordinate stuff within the application, whereas the second one is used to route events to listeners on the outside - this is what you would call a ["content-based router"](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ContentBasedRouter.html), since it will route messages depending on some value of the content of the message (in this case `documentProviderId`).

Now you are experiencing an error: When bus (1) uses bus (2) from within one of its own message handlers, the routed message does not seem to be sent.

It is not clear from the code you posted from `ExternalEventsBus` which `Send` method you are calling - but I can tell you that the method with the signature `public Task Send(object message, DocumentProvider documentProvider)` will only send a message if `documentProvider.RebusQueueConnectionString` is not null.

1. Did you verify that the connection string does in fact carry a value?
2. Why is there a `_connectionString` field in `ExternalEventsBus`? Should you have used that when creating the bus?
3. Do you remember to `await bus.Send(...)` (i.e. `await` the result of the asynchronous operation) each time you call the bus?

Comment: 1. Yes the connectrionstring have a value.
2. The _connectionString was just to test that the correct connectionstring (AzureServiceBus) was used when creating the ExternalEventBus. 

The Bus 2 (External) is using content routing where each account have it's separate queue. When we use Bus 2 outside Bus1 (In startup for example) this works just fine, but from within the Bus1 Handle function the message disappears.

Any theory?

Comment: just added bullet 3... :)

Comment: Yes it uses await Send from async methods and  or Task.Run(async()=>await Send(...)) from sync methods.

Comment: could you try and `bus.Send(...).Wait()` instead of that funny doubly-async-lambda thing you're doing there? :D

Comment: Sure I could try that, could it be the async operation that is not awaited so that the sending is aborted before it could completed?

Comment: my guess is that an aynchronous `bus.Send` is "escaping you" somehow, which causes any thrown exceptions to simply disappear....

Comment: I've checked the code now, all the functions are async Task all the way from the messagehandler down to Bus2 send command.
I'll have to debug the code to check 100% (only looked at the source on github) I do not have access to it from my home office. But I looks like it could be something else.